# Question on base conversion ( number theory)

Tags: number-theory

In which base does $25$ gets doubled when its digits are reversed?

Let the base be n

52(base n)= 2* 25(base n)

How can we write the above equation as

$5n+2= 2*2n+2*5$?

Comment: Why don't you try solving the equation you have written down and see if it works?

Comment: $52_n$ five two base n means $2$ in the units column & $5$  in the $n$'s column. So that is $2+5n$ as an algebraic expression.

Answer (score 2):

$52_{10}$ means you have $5$ times the base, which is $10$, plus two.  Similarly $52_n$ is the way you would write $5n+2$ in base $n$.  Similarly $25_n$ is the way you would write $2n+5$ in base $n$.  If you had a third digit to the left of the radix point it would represent how many $n^2$s there were in the number.  So the question is asking for what $n$ is $5n+2=2(2n+5)$